# What database does Stack Overflow use?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

I'm very curious to know which database system stackoverflow.com uses. Does anyone know? Is it key/value or RDBMS?

Comment: @CanSpice: It's not like it wasn't going to happen just because you can't do it :) @SpamKids: No you couldn't. You can't delete someone else's comment just by having a lot of rep. Moderators can, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 3):

StackExchange sites use the Microsoft stack, so the DB is Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: nice! but how do you know? :)